# Java Script getJSON properly not working in laravel 5.+?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5.1, getjson

Controller

```
public function getback(Request $request)
{


    $chart = DB::table('BirthChart_1')
             ->where('FileId', 123)
             ->get();



            foreach ($chart as $key ) {
                $f[] = [$key->k1,$key->k2,$key->k3,$key->k4,$key->k5,$key->k6,$key->k7,$key->k8,$key->k9,$key->k10];

            }

            return response()->json($f);
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("/getback", function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items.push(val);
    });
    alert(items);
    alert(items[0]);
    alert(items[1]);

  });
});
```

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/getback
>   Result...
>   `[[3,4,null,null,null,5,null,null,null,null]]`
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8000
>   Result

```
alert(items); // 3,4,,,,5,,,,
alert(items[0]); // 3,4,,,,5,,,,  (here I want 3)
alert(items[1]); // undefined (here ,I want 4)
```

What is my mistake in here ? or how to correct it properly ?

Comment: There is no `item`. Should be `items` which is plural.

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl Updated ..

Comment: That is a nested array... try `items[0][1]` or `data[0][1]` which is same thing.

Comment: why you tell like that what the reason for that but the same code properly working normal php server side,In laravel got problem @charlietfl

Comment: No idea what you mean. javascript doesn't run server side

Comment: What I mean the same code working normal php page but laravel frame work not working @charlietfl

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? You are getting the result in `$.getJSON()` so it must be working server side

Comment: sorry sir @charlietfl ,It's working on laravel but not properly working ,In normal php it's working perfect ,i got expect result as well.

Comment: You simply aren't providing enough details to explain your case. Did `items[0][1]` work or not?

Comment: Ya , It's working ,Thank you sir @charlietfl ,I got what i want

Answer (score 2):

Just Changed

```
alert(items[0][1]);
alert(items[0][2]);
```

I got answer form  @charlietfl Thank you sir ..